# TASM "required parameter missing"

Tags: assembly, tasm

I have recently begun coding in TASM and am currently working on creating a version of the UNO game. I thought of making a procedure that receives the draw pile offset, the player's "hand", the number of cards to draw, and adds that many from the draw pile. However, when trying to execute the file the assembler prints the message "required parameter missing". it is not labeled as an error or something. Does anyone have an idea?

picture of the message and code of the procedure are included.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHsx1.png)

the code:

```
proc DrawXCards
push bp
mov bp, sp
push ax
push bx
push cx
push dx
push si

mov bx, [bp+4] ; main array offset
mov cx, 0 ; count for finding index
mov dx, [bp+6] ; main array offset size (a constant)
find_index: ; searching for index in draw pile to begin drawing from
    cmp [byte ptr bx], 0
    jne break ; found index
    inc bx
    inc cx ; index
    cmp cx, dx
    jb find_index ; going through the entire array
    jmp finishsearching ; deck is empty in that case  - jmp to exit
break:
    add bx, cx ; bx now holds index
    jmp allocation ; now allocating begins from where values in main deck aren't zero   
allocation:
    mov si, [bp+8]
    mov cx, [si]  ; cards to draw in cx
    xor ch, ch
    mov si, [bp+10] ; hand offset - now find index to begin adding from
    push cx ; save amount of cards to draw
    mov cx, 0 ; count for find index in hand
    mov dx, [bp+12] ; hand size
    find_handindex:
         cmp [byte ptr si], 0
         je found_hand_index ;stop when value equals zero and begin allocation
         inc si
         inc cx
         cmp cx, dx ; cmp index to hand size
         jb find_handindex
         jmp hand_full ; deck is full and in that case - equals exit

    found_hand_index:
         add si, cx ; actual index to begin allocating
         jmp actual_allocation

    actual_allocation:
         pop cx ; return the nunber how many cards to draw
         allocation_loop:
             mov al, [byte ptr bx]
             mov [si], al
             mov [byte ptr bx], 0
             inc si
             inc bx
             loop allocation_loop
             jmp finishsearching



     hand_full:
         pop cx
         jmp finishsearching

     finishsearching:
          pop si
          pop dx
          pop cx
          pop bx
          pop ax
          pop bp
          ret 10
          endp DrawXCards
```

explanation to the code: the procedure receives the draw pile offset, the draw pile length (constant), player's "hand" offset, player's hand size (also constant - a relatively large one so it's not probable it will be reached) and numbers of cards to draw. In my code, I ignore cards with value of zero and skip them or replace them with actual value.

P.S: This is my first time posting in this forum, please do not get mad at me for breaking any conventions, rules or bad english.

Thank you!

Comment: `copy` is a [built-in command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy) for the command processor, it will not consider running your program.  You could type "copy.exe", but surely you'd consider giving your program a better name.

Comment: "when trying to execute the file the assembler prints" The assembler is only the program you're running with the `tasm` command. It isn't the assembler that displays your error, it is your attempt to run your program executable. (Like @HansPassant wrote the problem is there's an internal command by the same name you chose.)

Comment: Oh shoot, you're right..
Thank you! I wouldn't have gotten it without you guys!